# Include music app options into volume icon

Tags: 16.04, mate

I recently changed over to mate from unity on my laptop. Everything is great, brilliant even, but I am really missing Unity’s integration of music/ video apps into the volume icon. Is there a way of including this functionality in mate 16.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

[image]

To set it up:

- Install `mate-indicator-applet`, and `indicator-sound-gtk2`, using the software center, or using `apt-get install mate-indicator-applet indicator-sound-gtk2`, if they are not installed yet.
- Logout and login again, or reboot (Not sure if this is actually necessary)
- Right click on an empty space in the panel, select "add to panel", find "Indicator applet complete", and drag it onto the panel.

If you want to disable the old system tray volume control (which will still be there), go into the "Startup applications" utility (In the control center or in the menu), and uncheck the "Volume control" item (requires a logout / login to take effect).

Comment: Just to add to your solution. Both mate-indicator-applet and indicator-sound-gtk2 where both already installed. Go to System > Preferences > Look And Feel > Mate Tweak. Under the Interface section 'Panel Features' and make sure the 'Enable Indicators' option is checked.